# After Extending Shopware 6 Product Entity, How Do I Save The Data When New Product Is Created?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, shopware, shopware6

I extended the Shopware 6 `product` table following Shopware documentation [Adding complex data to existing entities](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities#creating-the-extension).

I have added an input field to accept user data, how do I save it to the database when the product is saved. I want the data available in `product.written` event payload.

[image: Seller Name Input Field]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `EntityExtension` only allows to add either associations or runtime only fields (evaluated during runtime and cannot be persisted), I assume you registered your own custom entity and associated it with `product`.

You can then use the `extension` property of the `product` entity to store values for associations to the extended entity.

I assume you did override `sw-product-settings-form` to place the field in the administration:

```js
Component.override('sw-product-settings-form', {
    template,
    inject: ['repositoryFactory'],
    computed: {
        sellerName: {
            get() {
                return this.product.extensions.yourEntity?.sellerName ?? null;
            },
            set(value) {
                if (!this.customer.extensions.yourEntity) {
                    this.$set(this.product.extensions, 'yourEntity', this.repositoryFactory.create('your_entity').create());
                }

                this.$set(this.product.extensions.yourEntity, 'sellerName', value);
            },
        },
    }
});
```

In your override's template:

```html
<sw-text-field
    v-model="sellerName"
/>
```

Changes to the field will then be persisted when saving the product. [Here's an example plugin](https://github.com/dneustadt/DneCustomerHeightExtension) that extends the customer module with an extension field in the same manner.